# FBSDKLoginButton Programmatic Height Constraint renders larger height than same GIDSignInButton Storyboard Height Constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-signin, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am increasing the size of the Facebook SDK SignIn Button (FBSDKLoginButton).

Facebook SDK source code adds a single constraint to the FBSDKLoginButton, `height = 28.0`. I remove this constraint in my `ViewDidLoad`:

```
print("constaints for FBSDKLoginButton BEFORE:")
for constraint: NSLayoutConstraint in btnFbSignIn.constraints {
    print(constraint)
    if(constraint.firstAttribute == .height) {
        btnFbSignIn.removeConstraint(constraint)
    }
}
```

*I remove any height constraints in my FBSDKLoginButton, there are two, as I have a height constraint constant of 55.0 in my Storyboard, print:*

```
constaints for FBSDKLoginButton BEFORE:
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000284d30 FBSDKLoginButton:0x7fac3c00c090'Log in'.width == 240   (active)>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000009f770 FBSDKLoginButton:0x7fac3c00c090'Log in'.height == 55   (active)>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000287ee0 FBSDKLoginButton:0x7fac3c00c090'Log in'.height == 28   (active)>
```

I then add my height constraint programmatically:

```
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[btnFbSignIn(55)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["btnFbSignIn": btnFbSignIn]))
```

Printing constraints on the `FBSDKLoginButton` after shows there are no height constraints associated with my `FBSDKLoginButton` at all now.

```
print("constaints for FBSDKLoginButton AFTER:")
for constraint: NSLayoutConstraint in btnFbSignIn.constraints {
    print(constraint)
    if(constraint.firstAttribute == .height) {
        btnFbSignIn.removeConstraint(constraint)
    }
}
```

*Print:*

```
constaints for FBSDKLoginButton AFTER:
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000284d30 FBSDKLoginButton:0x7fac3c00c090'Log in'.width == 240   (active)>
```

What is surprising is the the height constraint constant I add programmatically for `FBSDKLoginButton`renders a larger height than a Storyboard height constraint constant of 55.0 set on a `GIDSignInButton` component:[image]

And here is the constraints for the `GIDSignInButton`:[image]

**What could be making a constraint height constant of 55.00 * multiplier of 1.0 on the `FBSDKLoginButton` render differently than a constraint height constant of 55.00 * multiplier of 1.0 on the `GIDSignInButton`?**

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure `GIDSignInButton` ignores any height constraints. Setting mine to a height constraint of 100 with the `.wide` style seems to only render it 48 high. It also seems to include a padding of 4 for shadows.

> Possible values:
>
> - kGIDSignInButtonStyleStandard: 230 x 48 (default)
> - kGIDSignInButtonStyleWide: 312 x 48
> - kGIDSignInButtonStyleIconOnly: 48    x 48 (no text, fixed size)

See: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in_button